# Display all logs above info but save to file all logs above debug

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I would like to display all logs above the level `INFO` but save to file all logs above the level `DEBUG`. I understand how to set the level with `setLevel` but how can I save a log without displaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two handlers (`WARNING` level for the `StreamHandler`), perfectly explained in the [*cookbook*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules)

```
# create logger with 'spam_application'
logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```